# Does my website approve on Google AdSense

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense, ads

I have a website under construction in WordPress, I have plans to build that website for my personal article collection & earn money by sharing my knowledge with public.

(I will publish there my own article : genuine new article)

I'm using free template downloaded from https://wordpress.org/themes. & also remove text "Designed By xxxxxxxx" from footer.

(I will host my website on hosting server & also buy domain : not using any free service)

Is it possible to approve my website on Google AdSense with this theme? How many minimum number of articles & daily pageviews are required for Google AdSense approval?

Will the use of free template & removing 'Designed by' reject my account on Google AdSense?"

Comment: "*My major confusion is "Is the use of free template & removing 'Designed by' name rejects my account on google adsence?"*" - No. Make sure your website has an easy-to-navigate design (create a Sitemap, add it to GWT etc.), write unique, quality posts and generate some good UVs. And from what I've seen, websites under the age of 6 months are usually rejected. In any case, this is way **off-topic** on SO. [webmasters.se] might be better suited for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is *not* about programming.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question, I have habit find solution on this site b'cos of my major question are for programming, I will not publish off-topic question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some content for AdSense to approve your site, the content is more important than the theme. You'll also need some content to get traffic so that's not a real problem. I'll suggest you to first make two or three articles an then create an AdSense account, that should work.

You'll also need a plugin to inject ads on your site, look for AdSense plugins.

Comment: Did you mean that if I'm publish my site with this free template then it's doesn't matter? I just need good traffic & good and genuine article.

Comment: That's it, AdSense will check you have a genuine site and that advertisers will not be shocked if they see their ads on your site, but whether the template is free or specific, they don't care. And you don't need the traffic to get AdSense approval, just some decent content.

Comment: Got it....
Thanks
Thank you for your quick reply....